# AWS CLI without configuring access/secret keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

Need to access cross account EC2 describe/start instance API via AWS CLI without configuring access/secret keys in "aws configure".

Comment: Can you tell us more about your needs? For example, from where are you running this command? Why don't you want to use `aws configure`? Do you actually have a set of AWS credentials?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have default credentials stored for an account (Let's call it dev) but you want to run EC2 describe/start instance API on an instance which is in another account(Let's call it prod) via this account without configuring your prod credentials.

To achieve this you will use an IAM role, which has the **EC2:describeInstance** access needed in your Prod account. An authenticated user in your Dev account will assume a privileged IAM role in the Prod account with an API call to **STS:AssumeRole**. This API call will return temporary security credentials that the Dev user’s AWS CLI will automatically use to access resources in the Prod account.

Comment: Hey if this answer helped you, please mark it as accepted. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the credentials temporary via environment variables. If you pack this is an bash script, they only last for the execution.

```
#!/bin/bash
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=***
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=***
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-central-1

aws ec2 <your command>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a cli of an ec2, best way to do this is to use the IAM role attached to the instance which has permissions ec2:StartInstances and ec2:DescribeInstances for the target ec2.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET aws ec2...
```